# If a complex function $f(z)$ is discontinuous at $z_0$ then does that imply that the derivative $f'(z_0)$ does not exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Moreover if the implication is correct can then one use this result to test whether a line in the complex plane is a branch cut?

Say a function $g(z)$ has a branch cut along $(-\infty, 0)$.

One possible way to test for this discontinuity is to show that

$$\forall a\in (-\infty, 0) \quad \lim_{b \to 0^-} g(a+bi) \neq \lim_{b \to 0^+} g(a+bi)$$

Right?

But I could also show that $g'(z)$ does not exist right?

Comment: Branch cuts are non-unique.  One choses the contour to cut the plane in order to guarantee that the function is single-valued in the cut plane.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(z_0)$ exists, then $f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$ and hence $f$ is continuous at $z_0$.

Your example with branch-cuts, however, makes little sense as the function is *defined* only (or considered to be defined only) outside the cut, andtalking about derivative at a point outside the domain of definiiotn makes no sense. Even worse: In cases we want to introduce a branch cut in order to *make* an otherwise multivalued function single-valued, it may happen that the derivative exists happily (because we may have a lot of choice to pick the cut). Just think of the logarithm that requirs a cut whereas its derivative $z\mapsto \frac1z$ does not.

Comment: My current goal is to come up with a way to show that a function $g(z)$ has a branch cut along a certain line in the complex plane. If I compute $g'(z)$ and show that $g(z)$ is undefined along that line, would that immediately imply that a branch cut exists?